# When i try to import termcolor on repl.it, it just says the package operation failed

Tags: python, replit, termcolor

When i try to run `from termcolor import colored, cprint`, it keeps coming up with `Repl.it: Package operation failed.` Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://replit.com/talk/ask/What-does-Replit-Package-operation-failed-mean/37267#165845)

Comment: before, when i tried it worked on repl

Answer (score 0):

Although it is quite old, [`termcolor`](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/) is a very simple py module that should have no problems in replit. I myself have no issues importing and running [its example script on replit](https://replit.com/join/oamvayov-mavaddat).

Likely, the module packager files (`pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock`) have become corrupted on your replit due to [optimistic replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_replication) conflict, [adversarial machinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adversary_(cryptography)), catastrophic [hash collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision_(computer_science)), [quantum tunnelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling), or relativistic event horizon [information loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_information_paradox) — all known hazards of python programming.

[image: remove packager files as shown here]

To recover, try removing the packager files using the command below and trying to run the project again.

```sh
rm pyproject.toml poetry.lock
```